# Twitter bootstrap reset button

Tags: forms, button, twitter-bootstrap

How i can create a reset button using twitter bootstrap? same as the forms reset button which clears all the data?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
<input class="btn btn-danger" type="reset" value="Reset">
<!-- or -->
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">Reset</button>
```

If you don't want it to look "dangerously" remove `btn-danger` class.